# NoClassDefFoundError with a Custom Java Component in WCC

Tags: java, classpath, oracle-ucm

I'm attempting to a create a Custom Java component for [oracle-ucm](/questions/tagged/oracle-ucm).

It installs currectly however when I run the code I get:
`System code execution error. Unable to create service. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowes/content/edam/massMetaDataUpdate/service/ServiceApplication.`

component.hda file looks like so:

```
<?hda version="11.1.1.8.0PSU-2015-01-08 07:49:21Z-r123144" jcharset="UTF8" encoding="utf-8"?>
@Properties LocalData
ComponentName=LowesMassMetadataUpdater
blDateFormat=M/d{/yy}{ h:mm[:ss]{ a}}!mAM,PM!tAmerica/New_York
classpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/classes
hasPreferenceData=0
libpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/libs
preventAdditionalComponentDowngrade=0
version=2016_06_08(build 1)
@end
```

For reference the beginning of my service class looks like so:

package com.lowes.content.edam.massMetaDataUpdate.service;

```
import intradoc.server.Service;

public class MMUService extends Service
{  //this is the line that is throwing the error.
   private ServiceApplication app = new ServiceApplication();

   /** Default Constructor - Does Nothing */
   public MMUService() { }

   //rest of class omitted for brevity
}
```

My component is configured start in the MMUService class which is in the same package as the class that cannot be found. Both class files are directly in the same folder. So why can it find the initial service class, but not a contained helper class from the same package?

---

**Advanced Build Settings from Component Wizard**

All Blank except for:

**Custom Class Path:** `$COMPONENT_DIR/classes`
**Custom Library Path:** `$COMPONENT_DIR/libs`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would use a [ServiceHandler](http://www.redstonecontentsolutions.com/technical-blog/ucm-service-handlers-and-javafilters) instead of a Service.

Make sure you have an installID under Build > Advanced settings.

Some additional reading on building custom components can be found here:

- [1](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2015/08/custom-webcenter-content-components-links/)
- [2](http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2013/10/how-to-create-custom-component-in-webcenter-content-ucm.html)

Comment: Why a **ServiceHandler** instead of a **Service**? I'm building a component to take in an uploaded Excel File (Not a checked in Content Item) and process the contents of the file to perform a bunch metadata updates. 1 update per row in the file.  The service I'm building is to perform the bulk of the work I just described.

Comment: `> Service classes are easy to make, but are not very flexible. To make it more flexible, we need a ServiceHandler object. A service definition can reference methods from only one Service Class. However, that Service Class can be configured to have multiple Service Handlers, so that the code in a Service Handler is more portable and can be shared between services. The code is almost exactly the same, but it requires slightly more configuration.`

Comment: Is there a particular pattern or naming convention the Install ID is supposed to follow?

Comment: No. I usually just use the name of the component.

Comment: I just tried adding an Install ID with the name of the component. It didn't work.  If I remove the offening member variable it works though.

Comment: So, sounds like your code was not being properly compiled?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem.   Before the Application displayed the `NoClassDefFoundError` it was displaying a Logging error.  However, on Subsequent page Loads that error would disappear.

Turns out the logging error:

```
System code execution error. Unable to create service. Exception type is 'java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError'. 
Runtime error: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
               org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
               org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
                 Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log Runtime error: 
                       org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
                       org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
                       Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log Runtime error: 
                             org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
                             Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger does not implement Log
```

was the real cause of my issue. And digging into it reveals that the Classloader in WCC is loading a differerent Version of **Apache Commons Logging** than the application expects.

The fix was to create a Wrapper class of `SystemUtils` to implement `Log` and then set the system property `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` so that when classes call `LogFactory.getLog(classname.class);` They will get My WCC Logger class and sidestep the whole logging error issue.